# Unable to receive NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification specifically, but other notifications work

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-big-sur

```
-(void)monitor {
    NSNotificationCenter *notcenter;
    notcenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
    [notcenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(activeSpaceDidChange:) name:NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification object:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]];

- (void) activeSpaceDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"%@", notification.name);
}
```

Hey guys, does anyone have any info on this specific notification? For some reason, I seem to be able to get all other notifications, and if I put in `nil` for the name and receive all NSWorkspace messages, I can get all of them except `NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification`. All code snippets I have seen from people don't seem to be doing anything specific or different than what I have, so I have no idea why I wouldn't be able to get these notifications specifically.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple monitors open and it's getting confused which one is the active workspace/the one you are changing?

Comment: no, I'm testing just on my laptop itself with no external monitors. I've also tried creating spaces after I start the app just in case it couldn't track spaces created before it ran, but no luck.

Comment: figured it out. needed to run NSApplicationLoad().